# Validation rule to restrict who can be owner of a case

Tags: case, validation-rule, ownership

Building out email to case for our customer service team, we only have sales cloud. I want to restrict who can assign and be assigned a case from the queue, same group of users would need to be able to change the owner and be assigned as the owner.

I have tried to make a validation rule off the owner field but have not been successful. This is the idea and this works:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
    ISPICKVAL(Origin , "email"),
    Owner:User.Profile.Name  <> "Customer Care Rep"
)
```

The issue is that I need to have it include 2 different profiles and when I add it in like this:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
    ISPICKVAL(Origin , "email"), 
    OR(
        Owner:User.Profile.Name  <> "Customer Care Rep",
        Owner:User.Profile.Name  <> "Customer Care Manager",
    )
)
```

It won’t work. I have tried a few different things based off of common fields they share on user profile but nothing is working.

Any ideas? I’ve been at it for a while so worried I’m missing an obvious fix.

Comment: A general tip is that whenever you're checking multiple conditions for a single field, you need to use `OR()` when you're checking for equality and `AND()` when you're checking for inequality.

Answer (score 4):

This statement will always be true:

```
OR(
    Owner:User.Profile.Name  <> "Customer Care Rep",
    Owner:User.Profile.Name  <> "Customer Care Manager",
)
```

It's because if the profile is "Customer Care Rep", it won't be "Customer Care Manager", and vice versa.

To get this to work, just AND the conditions.

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
    ISPICKVAL(Origin , "email"),
    Owner:User.Profile.Name  <> "Customer Care Rep",
    Owner:User.Profile.Name  <> "Customer Care Manager"
)
```

I'm assuming you don't want the owner to have either of those two profiles.